# Number Key/value pair varies in REDIS

Tags: redis

I am trying to find the number of keys REDIS can accommodate. I fixed the maxmemory of REDIS `1471472` bytes and storing fixed size key/value pair. Sometimes it can accommodate 19 keys and sometimes 21.

Memory taken by each pair in case of 19 keys

```
1)18016 bytes
2)17984 bytes
3)17984 bytes
4)17984 bytes
5)52864 bytes
6)17952 bytes
7)17984 bytes
8)17984 bytes 
9)18112 bytes
10)17984 bytes
11)17920 bytes 
12)17984 bytes
13)17984 bytes 
14)17984 bytes
15)17984 bytes 
16)17984 bytes
17)18240 bytes 
18)17984 bytes 
19)17984 bytes
```

Total memory used = 1459104

Memory taken by each pair in case of 19 keys

```
1)18016 bytes
2)17984 bytes
3)17984 bytes
4)17984 bytes
5)18048 bytes
6)17952  bytes
7)17984 bytes
8)17984 bytes
9)18112 bytes
10)17984 bytes
11)17920 bytes
12)17984 bytes
13)17984 bytes
14)17984 bytes
15)17984 bytes
16)17984 bytes
17)18240 bytes
18)17984 bytes
19)17984 bytes
20)17984 bytes 
21)17856 bytes
```

Total memory used = `1460128`

Answer (score 0):

Its pointless to benchmark Redis with only 1.4 MB memory. You cannot extrapolate those numbers. The data you will eventually store is not going to be fixed size key value pairs.

Identify what you want to store, identify the available memory you will have at your disposal, and then run a realistic test. That is the only way to know for sure if Redis meets your needs.